# Derive a general result for the $n$th derivative of $\ln(1+x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm stuck on this problem: write down the four first derivatives of $f(x)= \ln(1+x)$ and hence derive a general expression for the nth derivative of $f$.

The first four derivatives  I found are respectively: $$\frac{1}{(1+x)},\; \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2},\;\frac{2}{(1+x)^3},\; \frac{-6}{(1+x)^4}. $$
I know I am missing something simple, but I can't see a pattern... any help would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sequence $1,1,2,6$ is the sequence $0!, 1!, 2!, 3!$

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the 'pattern' but I know how to proceed from here!

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$f^{(n)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\ln(1+x)$$

Then, the sequence of derivatives satisfies the recursive relation

$$f^{(n)}=-\frac{n-1}{1+x}f^{(n-1)}.$$

This yields:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\ln(1+x)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$$

where the repeated factor $-\frac{1}{1+x}$ leads to $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(1+x)^n}$, and the increasing factor $(n-1)$ leads to $(n-1)!$. You can also check this expression by induction.